# class and pass string as argument to method

Tags: c++

How to pass a string to a method in a class?

## code

```
class Txtbin{
    private:
        std::string input;
        std::string output = "output.png";
        void error();

    public:
        Txtbin();
        void run();
};

Txtbin::Txtbin(){

}

void Txtbin::error(const char* str){
    throw std::runtime_error(str);
}

void Txtbin::run(){
    if(input == ""){
        error("Input file not defined");
    }
}
```

## error

```
# g++ -std=c++11 txtbin.cpp -o txtbin `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
txtbin.cpp:30:6: error: prototype for ‘void Txtbin::error(const char*)’ does not match any in class ‘Txtbin’
 void Txtbin::error(const char* str){
      ^
txtbin.cpp:14:8: error: candidate is: void Txtbin::error()
   void error();
        ^
```

Comment: I'm new to C++ so no I don't know what it means. Maybe you could tell me?

Comment: You declare `void error();`  but define `void Txtbin::error(const char* str)`??
`

Comment: If I know what I'm doing wrong I wouldn't start this question

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++? It's not very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mentioned, you are declaring `void error();` but defining `void error(const char* str);`. Put `const char* str` parameter in the declaration too, inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
prototype for ‘void Txtbin::error(const char*)’
does not match any in class ‘Txtbin’
```

You're trying to define `Txtbin`'s `void error(const char*)` function, but it does not have one.

```
candidate is: void Txtbin::error()
```

It does, however, declare a `void error()` function, without the parameter. Since you actually use that parameter in the implementation, you probably want to add it to its declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, void error() requires no parameter. However later you create void error(const char* str) which has a parameter.

```
class Txtbin{
    private:
        string input;
        string output = "output.png";

    public:
        Txtbin();
        void error(const char*); //This is what you need.
        /* void error(); THIS IS WHAT YOU HAD */
        void run();
};

void Txtbin::error(const char* str)
{
  //Whatever
}
```